# Limit items Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I want to show Repeater only 5 items. How do I do that?
I do not want to use the paging.
How do I limit the Repeater control?

Answer (score 0):

Set the DataSource to have only 5 items.

Comment: How can I tell repeater limit?

Answer (score 0):

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />|
        <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /><br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{
    var p1 = new Product { ID = 1, Description = "Product 1" };
    var p2 = new Product { ID = 2, Description = "Product 2" };
    var p3 = new Product { ID = 3, Description = "Product 3" };
    var p4 = new Product { ID = 4, Description = "Product 4" };
    var p5 = new Product { ID = 5, Description = "Product 5" };
    var p6 = new Product { ID = 6, Description = "Product 6" };

    var products = new List<Product> { p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6 };
    rptProducts.DataSource = products.Take(5).ToList();
    rptProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank. But I data with the data source to the Repeater I. How can I tell repeater limit?

Comment: I'm showing you how, use Take() - products.Take(5).ToList().That means the limit is 5

Comment: Thank
You can do this with a SqlDataSource?

Comment: Yes you can - ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(5);

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sds_Title" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FaravajConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TitleNews]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
I gave this SqlDataSource to the repeater. Now I want to show Repeater only 5 record.
How do I do this?

Comment: SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [TitleNews]

Comment: I do not want to limit Dytasvrs. Dytasvrs the data I need.
My intention is to limit the repeater.
How should I limit repeater?

Comment: I've given you more than enough options.Use one or use a combination of a few of them to achieve the desired result